# Big execution time differences each refresh with pdo/mariadb

Tags: php, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I suppose mariadb is working similarly to mysql, this is what I'm using, and I know there is a cache system.

My problem and what I don't understand, is that the pages that I refresh takes a long time to refresh, but the time is not constant at all. Details later.

**On page A:**

85% of the time, it takes ~7 seconds to execute.

10% of the time, it takes ~27 seconds.

5% of the time it takes under 1 second (when I refresh in very short intervals).

**On page B:**

80% of the time, it takes ~5 seconds.

Sometimes it's ~2.5 seconds.

Sometimes it's less than a second.

One time it has been >60 seconds, triggering an error.

My code is not changing, it's just observation and refreshing with F5.

**Details:**

I have a MyISAM table, that gets roughly 150k new rows ("insert") per day.
I am looking to query this table every minutes ("select").
The max rows it could have at a time might range between 50,000,000 and 4,750,000,000...
I'm using PHP to run the queries on the same server.

Structure I'm using currently:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticks` (
 `primary` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `pairs` text NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(18,8) NOT NULL,
 `daily_volume` decimal(36,8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary`),
 KEY `datetime` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4007125 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Data sample :

```
|primary | datetime            | pairs    | price          | volume           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|5810228 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_HUC  | 0.00002617     | 6.08607929       |
|5810213 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_BELA | 0.00002733     | 8.83542600       |
|5810224 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_FLDC | 0.00000374     | 12.72654326      |
|5810234 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_NMC  | 0.00037099     | 4.06446745       |
|5810219 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_CLAM | 0.00070798     | 13.65356478      |
|5810220 | 20/01/2018 21:34:02 | BTC_DASH | 0.07280004     | 423.88604591     |
|1706999 | 11/01/2018 17:09:01 | USDT_BTC | 13590.45341401 | 398959280.2620621|
```

I have created an index ("normal" index) on datetime.

> The query on page A that takes 7 seconds to run with pdo, but ~0.0007 in phpmyadmin :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pairs)
FROM ticks
```

> Every heavy computations after this first query takes ~0.5 seconds total most of the time since I indexed datetime.

However, it sometimes takes between 25 and 35 times longer to run for unknown reasons. This is the query that is used (a loop runs it 100 times) :

```
SELECT datetime, price
FROM ticks
WHERE datetime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
AND pairs = \''.$data['pairs'].'\'
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I'm not going further into explaining page B because this page is less critical for me and I'm comfortable with the avg execution time related to the number of operations made on this page. My only interrogation is the wide range of execution times that can occur here too.

**Questions:**

1-How can the execution time differences be so wide, how can I have my pages running in under 1 sec, as it happens sometimes ? My sql queries are extremely simple and fast on the database alone. I believe the db and the php server is located on the same machine.

In particular, I'm wondering why a query would run 10,000 slower with pdo than with phpmyadmin. 7/0.0007 being 10k, there has to be a huge problem here.

Indexing pairs is not changing anything.

2-Have you seen anything incorrect in what I explained that could lead to a fix and improvement of performances? Do you have particular advises to have increased performance in the presented case? For instance, I've been wondering if **MyISAM** was efficient in my case (I believe so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is essentially *no* reason to use MyISAM any more, especially for performance.

7 seconds is terrible for a page load.  How much of that is MySQL actions?  Add some timers in the code.  This will find out which query is the slowest and let's improve it.  (I would guess that one unnecessarily slow query is at the root of your problem.)

"~0.0007" smells like the Query Cache kicked in and it did not really execute the query.  I ignore that.

With MyISAM, `INSERTs` block `SELECTs`.  That could explain the troubles during the insert part of the day.

The table is confusing -- you have a `TIMESTAMP` (resolution to second), yet there is a "daily_volume" which sounds like a resolution to the "day".

I see `TEXT`.  How long are the rows?  If less than 255, use `VARCHAR`, not `TEXT`.  That would allow you to add `INDEX(pairs)`, which allow`SELECT DISTINCT(pairs) FROM ticks` to run a lot faster.

But, instead of that index, add `INDEX(pairs, datetime)` in order to make the second `SELECT` run *much* faster.

Shrinking the table size will help some in speed.  (By some, I mean anywhere between 10% and 10x, depending on a lot of factors.)

Your decimal sizes are excessive.  Find the worst (probably `BRKA`) and shrink the `m,n` of `DECIMAL(m,n)`.  Currently you are using 9 and 15 bytes for those two columns.  You might consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes, ~7 *significant* digits) or `DOUBLE` (8 bytes, ~16 digits).

See my [*notes on converting to InnoDB*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) .  Be aware that the disk footprint might double or triple.  (Yes this is an advantage of MyISAM.)

Consider whether some other column (or combination of columns) is unique.  If you have such, jetison the column `primary` and make that column(s) the `PRIMARY KEY`.  If it happens to be `(pairs, datetime)`, then that will give a further performance boost to some queries.

"Indexing pairs is not changing anything." -- Since you can't index a `TEXT` column without using "prefixing" and prefixing is virtually useless, I am not surprised.

Could you show me a sample of the data?  I am not familiar with what a "pair" is.

An index *starting with* `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` is rarely useful; get rid of it unless you have another query that benefits from it.

As for the Query Cache -- size should be no more than 50M.  Does the data not change for 23 hours of the day, then there is a flurry of inserts?  This would be a good case for using the QC.  (*Most* production servers are better off turning it `OFF`.)  Going above 50M *may* slow down performance.

After you have addressed most of my suggestions, some other issues may bubble to the surface.  That is, I expect you to come back with another Question to finish improving the performance for your app.

Comment: The biggest fixes _for that query_:  `pairs VARCHAR(40)` plus `INDEX(pairs, datetime)`.  (The '40' is arbitrary -- comfortably more than your 15 and less than the next cutoff that _might_ cause trouble (191).  That is, _this_ `SELECT` will be helped but these.  The switch to InnoDB and other recommendations will help other things.

Comment: Thank you. I took some time to apply your suggestions: Renamed daily_volume into volume. Changed TEXT into VARCHAR(40). This alone made the query run into 1.5s on avg instead of 7s. Deleted datetime index. Created a multi-field key index: create index datetime_pairs on TABLE (`pairs`, `datetime`);. The query ran into ~0.002s instead of 1.5s. No run time change for the datetime based query. What did you meant by "BRKA" and shrinking table? Leaving this. Changed volume from decimal(36,8) to decimal(20,8). Changed price from decimal(18,8) to decimal(14,8). This improved execution by ~15%.

Comment: Changed MyISAM to InnoDB. Saw no performance change, but it might have improved things related to locks on Inserts. As for a primary (pairs, datetime), unfortunately, it seems ~0.0001% rows are not unique. Which is enough to make it a bad idea to make that primary? My query_cache_limit=2097152 and query_case_size=67108864. Which slightly above 50M. Is this a problem? I added data samples on my post. I might have further questioning as I encounter poor performance on future results.

Comment: BRKA is perhaps the most expensive (think size needed for `price`).  Do you really have two prices in the same second?  QC size of 64M -- OK.  Start a new question, with new `CREATE TABLE`, etc, if you have problems.

Comment: @Aada-Ea - And, what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Each pairs are getting added every minutes by insert queries which result in different prices being added the same second. This is a table meant to track price variations ("ticks"). innodb_buffer_pool_size=2147483648. Cpanel says Physical and Virtual memory = 15.63 GB

Comment: "Each pairs" -- How many rows are inserted every few minutes?  What does the `INSERT` look llike?

Comment: Between 100 and 500 every minutes. Insert is INSERT INTO ticks(pairs, price, volume) VALUES (:pairs, :price, :volume)

Comment: @Aada-Ea - 10/second is not fast.  100/second begins to get interesting.  But I see a contradiction:  "4,750,000,000" would take _decades_ to `INSERT`.  (No sane computer program lasts that long.)

Comment: 4,750,000,000 was an estimation of the max rows the table could contain, in the case I decided to not split the data sources (95 tables of 50,000,000 rows VS 1 table of 4,750,000,000 with a new 'source' column). I considered having 95 independant tables under InnoDB. Max INSERT per minute should be ~500 currently. Inserts performance looks fine to me and hardly improvable, what I'm cautious about is the insert datetime (it takes ~2 sec to insert, but sometimes datetime goes above hh:mm:25, which I believe is a problem related to the data source provider, nothing I can do about it).

Comment: @Aada-Ea - Is it 500/minute per table?  That would be closer to 1000 rows/sec being inserted.  _Usually_ it is a bad design to have 95 'identical' tables.  That is another discussion.

Comment: Max insert should be ~500/min on a given table, and ~80/min per table on avg. I didn't know it was a bad design, but if InnoDB can handle billions of rows while having nearly the same select and insert performance as with ~6 millions of rows currently then I should probably add this 'source' column. My other fear was to have some kind of table corruption, rendering 95 data sources unusable instead of just 1. But no need to go into further details than that as it is another subject.

Comment: I should add that for some reasons, the page still randomly executes in 3-4 seconds (still uncommon). 90% of the time it's between 0.4 and 1.25s now. Maybe some problems related to the hosted server.

Comment: @Aada-Ea - On spinning drives (as opposed to SSDs), 95*80 rows inserted/minute is needs some careful planning.  Are you "batching" or using `LOAD DATA`?  (This Comment applies to both MyISAM and InnoDB.)

Comment: @Aada-Ea - As for "corruption", MyISAM has more risk of corruption than InnoDB.  A power failure almost always requires "repairing" MyISAM tables.

Comment: The random slow vs fast `SELECT` is simply because MyISAM has locked the table to do the `INSERTs`.  InnoDB does not have that characteristic.  Tell us more about how the `INSERTs` are done.  There are tricks that may help.

Comment: It's weird that I am getting random slowdowns because I converted all my MyISAM tables into InnoDB. I might still use 95 separate tables, since the columns have a chance to be different between each sources, and cron jobs would probably needs to be separated anyway. As far as I know if I'm running 1 cron of 95 instructions it will be slower than running 95 crons at the exact same time. Let's say source 41 is having server problems, it will delay inserts for source 42 to 95.

Comment: As for the inserts, I am simply using cron jobs triggering php pages in which pdo is running insert queries in a foreach loop which source is a json returned by an API.

Comment: 95 processes pounding on MySQL at the same time will run into a different set of inefficiencies.  If you run 95 cron jobs hourly, changing to `n * * * *`, where `n` is mostly different for each job.  This spreads them out across the hour.

Comment: @Aada-Ea - Is that 1 row per `INSERT` statement?  Batch them so that you do 100 at a per `INSERT` and autocommit if practical.

Comment: As for the Inserts, autocommit is enabled by default. I've read on another thread that using `query` instead of `prepare`+`execute` was more effective in PDO. I then used `query` to insert the values in one go as you suggested. Avg execution time went from 0.2 to 0.004, so ~50 times faster. This will certainly reduce server load.

Comment: As for the crons. Running all inserts and selects every minutes is a requirement; I can't spread them accross an hour, each queries needs to run every minutes each. And I believe that having 1 big cron instead of 95 cron jobs will randomly result in some huge delays, the instructions being processed line after line and not at the same time. If this is only a server load issue, then I should pay for an appropriate hosting service. I might need to open a new thread to discuss how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the execution time differences be so wide, how can I have my pages running in under 1 sec, as it happens sometimes ? My sql queries are extremely simple and fast on the database alone.

It's impossible to answer this question with any degree of certainty without analyzing your platform, monitoring the performance each component, reviewing the code and all the queries, etc. This is way beyond the scope of SO.

What can be said is:

- It's unlikely that it has anything to do with PDO itself (or PHPMyAdmin for that matter)
- It's typical of a concurrency problem - that is unless you have a server and a database dedicated to rendering "page A" *only*, other requests and queries happening at the same time can impact performances
- MyISAM is notoriously bad at handling a large volume on insert because it uses *table locking* (in short, it locks all the table every time you make an insert). InnoDB use *row based locking* which would very probably be much more efficient with 150k writes a day. To quote the MySQL Documentation:

> Table locking enables many sessions to read from a table at the same time, but if a session wants to write to a table, it must first get exclusive access, meaning it might have to wait for other sessions to finish with the table first. During the update, all other sessions that want to access this particular table must wait until the update is done.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the table from a MyISAM type to InnoDB. This might improve performance regarding locking results. Noting that the Inserts are happening every minutes too.